# SVG fill transparent

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use wave SVG and I have a background image at the body
but I want the SVG to be filled with transparent so it shows the body background-image
but when I try to make it `fill: transparent` or `fill-opacity: 0`

it just hides all the wave shapes. So is there is a way to replace #000000 with something transparent that shows body background-image?

Here is an example code
https://jsfiddle.net/nLt2vu4k/

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5131560.jpg");
}

header {
    min-height: 20rem;
    background-color: cyan;
    position: relative;
}

.shape {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.shape svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(128% + 1.3px);
    height: 163px;
}

.shape .shape-fill {
    fill: #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<header>
<div class="shape">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for helping,
Best regards.

Comment: You've got a header with background-color cyan behind the black svg so when you make the svg transparent the whole of the header shows through. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to mask the header so it has the wavy shape and shows the cat background (with a wavy top edge) or are your trying to do something else?

Comment: I just want to replace the #000000 of the wavy shape to transparent (with the cyan background) so it will show the cat image. If I just put fill: transparent it will show the cyan background and not the cat image. Thank you for responding.

Comment: The shape does not have a cyan background, the header does. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Here is an example what I'm trying to explain: https://prnt.sc/131m58d
So I want to make it something like that.

Comment: You can't cut through the background of another element like that. Perhaps a mask but I'm not overly confident even then.

Comment: Yes you can by using clipPath

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked, I just want to check if it's possible to do it in this way... 
Otherwise is there is any idea to make like the image I sent or its not possible at all?
Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clipPath with your svg

To have a nice result you might have to edit your SVG

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5131560.jpg");
}

header {
  min-height: 20rem;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.shape svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(128% + 1.3px);
  height: 163px;
}

.shape .shape-fill {
  fill: #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="shape">
      <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <clipPath id="myClip">
        <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly how I want. But is there is a way to make it full width because when I make it on full screen it just stops at half of the screen. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Yes you can add a pattern tag in the clipPath tag to make it repeat

Comment: Or you could also have a wider SVG that represent like 3 waves

Comment: Alright, I'll try to do it. Thank you so much for your time and for your answer. Best regards.

Comment: No bother , Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

For transparent you can define "fill-opacity" to 0 in path:

```html
<html>

<body>
<header>
<div class="shape">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill" fill-opacity="0"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this solution is perfect to make hotspot clickable yet transparent so you can see image underneath - exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new svg to cover the header background, and remove the header background-color.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/5131560.jpg");
}

header {
min-height: 20rem;
position: relative;
}

.shape {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 0;
}

.shape svg {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="shape">
<svg width="671" height="221" viewBox="0 0 671 221" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 0H671V195C375 304 282 14 0 195V0Z" fill="#0ff"/>
</svg>

</div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/7z1L5xdo/3/